# Is dark UI pleasing to general app consumers?

Tags: color, color-theory, interface-design, user-experience, applications

I noticed there is not so many dark apps on the app store. With few exceptions such as Spotify, it makes me wonder. On the other hand, Android seems to embrace dark colors a bit more.

Is there any specific danger in designing dark UI such as the one below that I am working on?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Quite a common question this across multiple stacks - check out Marcos's answer here http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35837/why-do-most-websites-use-a-white-background

Comment: I don't think there's any danger. Depending on what your app is trying to do it could help with the feel and usability a lot.

Comment: ...also, I know this isn't part of your question and I don't know what final icons you will use but I'd suggest using a thicker line on your "bell" icon. the heart just about works but the bell is fading away a little.

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to continue on your current path.  Without a doubt, the visually lighter interfaces are more popular - but there is no danger in simply using a darker color scheme.  The dangers come from specific implementation decisions.

Some other dark mobile apps for iOS include:

- Resy
- most National Geographic apps
- Moves
- Slingshot
- Elevate
- Expedia
- Medium

Hope these provide inspiration for what you're going for.

-A

Answer (score 1):

It has more to do with what's in vogue at the moment. A few years ago, all apps hard dark UI with much more gloss. It's really up to you or your client.